# AWS Managed Microsoft Active Directory:- Cross region replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, aws-directory-services

Thanks for your time and response in advance.

I have setup a AWS Managed Microsoft AD in Region 1 (in a VPC).

For latency reasons, I want to setup another instance of the AD in Region 2.

**And then have replication enabled between them.**

**Is that possible ?**

If so, can you please point in the right direction

***Ps***:

I went thru this re:Invent 2017 presentation.
[Deep Dive on Active Directory – From One to Many AWS Regions (WIN302)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=torTUAcQo8M)

That lecture concentrates on installing and setting up your own Active directory.

For AWS managed Microsoft AD, they refer to the video

[AWS re:Invent 2017: AWS Directory Service for Microsoft Active Directory Deep Dive (WIN403)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyspfGRF9Bw)

However, there is no reference to the cross region replication in there.

Comment: Now it's possible. Here is a blog about it. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/multi-region-replication-now-enabled-for-aws-managed-microsoft-active-directory/